# How to close the browser after successful execution of .bat file automatically

Tags: batch-file

Here I have the .bat file script to execute a program automatically in chrome browser. It is working like expected.

```
@echo off
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" CHROME.EXE filepath.php
```

But after successful execution of this script browser should close automatically. How to achieve this ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know when it's finished, is it immediate?

Comment: We don't know when it is finished . This batch file will execute for every 5 min .

Comment: You'll need someway of knowing then, as the browser won't close on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are two scenarios:

1. You only kill the process after a successful execution of the PHP script. In that case, from the PHP script, call:

---

```
$result= shell_exec('taskkill /f /im "chrome.exe"');
```

2. If you want to kill the process regardless of what happens inside the PHP script, kill it from the bat file directly using:

---

```
taskkill /f /im "chrome.exe"
```

Comment: Browser closing immediately, even it is not waiting , upto the execution of script.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to wait for Chrome to load before killing the process, you can wait a specific amount of time using the code below, example is 3 seconds:

```
timeout /t 3
```